# How can I find out why ESLint performance is slow?

Tags: node.js, typescript, eslint

I'm trying to profile my application's usage of ESLint. The only profiling tool I've been able to find provided by ESLint is the `TIMING=1` env variable. I've combined with `DEBUG=eslint:cli-engine` to see the timing per file, and the results still are completely unclear to me.

This is the full output (linting on a single file). The timing results show the longest result taking 400ms (which it claims is 42% of the overall time), however the command actually took 50s to run

```
TIMING=1 DEBUG=eslint:cli-engine npx --node-options='--max-old-space-size=16240' eslint --fix --quiet --cache ./src/_test/some-test.int.test.ts
  eslint:cli-engine Lint ./src/_test/some-test.int.test.ts +0ms
  eslint:cli-engine Linting complete in: 50192ms +49s
Rule                                    | Time (ms) | Relative
:---------------------------------------|----------:|--------:
import/named                            |   394.573 |    42.4%
@typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises  |   278.482 |    29.9%
import/order                            |   174.813 |    18.8%
import/extensions                       |    11.753 |     1.3%
react/jsx-no-constructed-context-values |     7.815 |     0.8%
import/no-unresolved                    |     6.491 |     0.7%
@typescript-eslint/naming-convention    |     5.245 |     0.6%
react/no-unstable-nested-components     |     3.266 |     0.4%
import/no-relative-packages             |     2.383 |     0.3%
css-modules/no-unused-class             |     2.338 |     0.3%
```

Are there any other profiling tools I can use to see where this other 50 seconds are coming from? Any ideas on where the hangup might lie?

Comment: You can always use [`--inspect` and your local Chrome profiler](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#--inspecthostport).

Answer (score 0):

There is beginning of explanation in this [issue comment](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/issues/1367):

> import plugin has to parse every dependency, whereas "normal" ESLint rules only need to inspect a small portion of the current file (that has already been parsed). The import parse time is recorded as part of the rule execution.

You'll also notice poor performances for type aware linting rules because it takes time to build the TS AST. More [info here](https://typescript-eslint.io/troubleshooting/performance-troubleshooting)

Comment: Thanks for the link, looking at that issue it seems like the complaint is reported slowness, whereas what I'm seeing is slowness not captured by the timing output. If 42% of linting time is 400 ms then where is the other 48s being spent?

Comment: Ok I misread a bit your question then. I'm pretty sure this related to typescript. If you remove your `@typescript-eslint` rules, you should see a major difference.